# cmake linking error to external library

Tags: cmake

I have been facing the issue of linking the cmake to libass libraries. The project directory that we have is picturised below

```
MainApp ( it contains the CmakeLists.txt)
|
|
|--cmake/libs ( this contains FindLibass.cmake)
|
|
|--src
|   |
|   |-Decoder ( it contains the Sources.cmake)
|           |              |--Subtitle.cpp
```

The “FindLibass.cmake“ is a sub-module of MainApp  that maintains the paths to the Libass external library and the header files.
The “Sources.cmake” is the part of code that maintains the Decoder specific code.

The Decoder code has been amended to make use of libass headers , but when it comes to linking to the library. It fails in the code  as below

```
Subtitle.cpp:(.text+0x68d): undefined reference to `ass_library_init()'
Subtitle.cpp:(.text+0x6fa): undefined reference to `ass_set_message_cb(ass_library*, void (*)(int, char const*, __va_list_tag*, void*), void*)'
Subtitle.cpp:(.text+0x70a): undefined reference to `ass_renderer_init(ass_library*)'
```

The syntax for the FindLibass.cmake is below

```
set(LIBASS_INCLUDE_DIR ${LIBASS_SEARCH_PATH})

FIND_PATH(LIBASS_INCLUDE
         NAMES ass/ass.h
         PATHS "${LIBASS_INCLUDE_DIR}/include"  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
 )

FIND_LIBRARY(LIBASS_LIBRARIES
         NAMES "libass.so"
         PATHS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/libass/lib"   NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
```

Comment: Have you used `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARY` to link your application against the library?

Comment: TARGET_LINK_LIBRARY has been used in the CMakeLists.txt to link with the libass library.  The issue comes from a "Subtitle.cpp" that is in a sub-directory named Decoder.

Comment: Thanks for the support . The issue has been fixed.

Comment: @Kamlesh Feel free to post an answer to your own question explaining how you resolved the problem. In case anyone with a similar problem happens to stumble on this question in the future.

Comment: @Peter If Peter's comment answered the question, I think it would be fair to allow him to phrase it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Awaiting clarification

Comment: The Solution  was to very the file "CMakeCache.txt". cmake generates the cache file on every execution, in my case the cache was getting corrupted ( dont know how ). I just had to clean the environment and fix it.